# Hide Advertising Banner in Mobile View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got stuck to solve this.

its working, it can hide banner in mobile view. but there are somtething wrong. the banner show behind from my content site. its look like the banner gonna be background of my site.

please anyone help me.

```css
#largeAds {
    width:728px;
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

    #smallAds{
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 468px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
    #largeAds { display: none }
    #smallAds{display: block;}
}
```

```html
<div id="largeAds">Large ads (728 x 90)</div>
<div id="smallAds">Small ads (468 x 60)</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code**, please edit your question to add in full code so someone can have a look at it. There is no code for `my content site` you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  #largeAds { display: none ! important }
  #smallAds{display: block; ! important}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but it will work

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 99999px)' href='css/large.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 468px) and (max-width: 750px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

now if you put your individual css in those it will load perfectly i use this for all of my sites :) i hope this helps you out